# Trying to extract only part of a string from a single line from a text file in c++

Tags: c++

Okay this is the second time Ive looked for help for my program, I know I nearly got it but I cant figure it out. So right now Im trying to write a program that has the user input the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy and return it as month date, year. So 01/01/1990 becomes January 1st, 1990. I need to use a text file that has the names of the months beside their corresponding numbers. So the list of the text file looks like this:

```
01January
02February
03March
```

.. and so on.

So far I have this:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string thedate; //string to enter the date
    string month; // this string will hold the month
    ifstream myfile ("months.txt");
    cout << "Please enter the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, include the slashes: " <<      endl;
    cin >> thedate;

    month = thedate.substr( 3, 2 );
    string newmonth;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile,newmonth);
            newmonth.find(month);



            cout << newmonth << endl;

        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    return 0;
}
```

So I have been able to extract the month from the user input, and store that as month, Im just not too sure how search the text file for that month, and return only the name of the month into a new string, only from that line. Right now if I enter 02/05/1990, it will output

```
05
05
05
05
05
.. for 12 lines.
```

I'm new to programming so any help is appreciated.

Also, I am only about 3 weeks into my programming course, and we haven't really learned functions, or arrays yet. So if you do have any help to offer, please avoid arrays and functions. I also understand it is easier to not read from a text file, but this is a requirement from my class to read it from the text file, so I need it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried asking a classmate or professor for help?  We're not really here to do your homework for you.  Especially with arbitrary restrictions like "no arrays or functions please".

Comment: That loop should be `while (std::getline(myfile, newmonth))`. You might also be interested in the documentation of `find`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: No arrays? No problem, you should be using a `std::vector` instead anyway.

Comment: I understand you guys arent here to do homework for me, Im not asking for you to write the code out for me, but if you could explain the syntax or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The `string::find` function (that you already used) returns the position of the search string (-> month). You can now use the `string::substr` function to extract the part of the string you are looking for.

Hope that helps for a start.